# Creating columns across all the spreadsheet + transpose the data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm running API requests to export data from third party to a Google Spreadsheet.
This script will be running automatically on a weekly basis (for report purposes).
In this Google Spreadsheet, I need to:

1. Create columns across all the sheets (they are all structured in the same way).
2. Transpose the data from previous week to the newly created columns.
3. Delete the old data from last week in the sheet named 'raw data'
4. Hide this sheet name 'raw data'

I've created a script with the 4 tasks I need Google Sheet to perform.
I'm guessing there are some issues with my functions/constants in my following script. I just need one function that nests all the other needed 'subfunctions' inside.
A bit of help to fix this would be appreciated. I feel I'm almost there :)

```
function columnCreation() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0,1,2,3,4,5];
  const range = sheet.getRange('D1:H55').getValues();
  const newrange = sheet.getRange('I1:M55');
  const rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  const today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "MM/dd/yyyy");

  sheet.insertColumnsAfter(8,5);
  sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
  newrange.setValues(range);
  sheet.getRange('D1').setValue(today).setNumberFormat("MMMM DD");
  }

function clearAllContent() {
 var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Raw Data').getRange();
 range.clearContent();
}
function hideSheet() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Raw Data').hideSheet();
}
```

Comment: Can you further explain what you are trying to achieve? As per the current explanation I understand all functions run correctly but you want one to run them all, is that right?

Comment: Hi @Kessy, thanks for your reply and sorry if I wasn't clear in my request. Basically I want to achieve the 4 tasks I listed above. However my script is actually not working, so I'd like some help to fix it. I think I'm getting confused at the functions/constants level https://imgur.com/a/BNCr5jp

Answer (score 0):

As an answer for the comment:

The error shown is on line 4 which refers to line 3 var `sheets` which is not a single sheet but an array of them.

To solve it you have to select which of the sheets you want to select. As an example, if there is only one Sheet, you have to choose `0`:

```js
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const range = sheet.getRange('D1:H55').getValues();
```

Comment: Hi @Kessy, I actually want to do 1. and 2. (create columns and data transposition) on all the sheets. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: For instance I changed the script to `const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0,1,2,3,4,5];` to make the changes on the first 6 sheets. However, the script only change the last sheets, not all the sheets.

Comment: What do you mean by create columns and data transposition? Have you checked on [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) and then for the same range on the new sheet [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)? Also, to apply the same to all the sheets why don't you loop around them and set the values in?

Comment: Basically I have a table that it's updated every months. To automate the process, data are copied from one month, and transpose to further columns (as per my script above). Everything is working, but I just need my script to apply to all the sheets on my spreadsheet. You mentioned looping around the sheets and set values in. Could you explain a little bit more? I'm sorry if it looks obvious, I'm quite a beginner programmer and I'm not sure how to apply "for i = ..." to my case

Comment: I tried to add `var sheet = ss.getSheets().length; for (var i=0, i<sheet; i++)` after `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`  but it did not work